# navigate through frame or text block

Tags: navigation, uwp, uwp-xaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeG2B.png)want to navigate from frame which contain text block,i  am trying given below code at mainpage.xaml and mainpage.xaml.cs but nothing happens.please help me out i am new to uwp -app dev and any suggestion please provide

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="Assets\info_footer.png"  Stretch="Fill" />
            <TextBlock  Text="Sign in" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,4,200,3" FontSize="32" />
            <TextBlock  Text="Sign up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="190,4,10,3" FontSize="32"/>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame" Margin="4,4,220,3" Tapped="MyFrame_Tapped" >



            </Frame>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame1" Margin="210,4,10,3" Tapped="MyFrame1_Tapped" >

            </Frame>

namespace CustomSplash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            RemoveGap();
        }
        public async void RemoveGap()
        {

            await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
        }

        private void MyFrame_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(signin));
        }

        private void MyFrame1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(signup));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"Help me learn programming"* type of questions aren't useful to future visitors. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree to @IInspectable comments

> saying Help me learn programming" type of questions aren't useful to
>   future visitors.

However my answer will correct the mistakes that you are doing and will nudge you in correct direction.

**Your Grid should be something like below**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Transparent">
    <Image Source="Assets\info_footer.png"  Stretch="Fill" />
    <TextBlock  Text="Sign in" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
    <TextBlock  Text="Sign up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
    <Frame Name="MyFrame" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

When you are in a page with a frame which you are using to show different views, you do not need to use multiple frames for each page. you can use single Frame for Navigation. However I would suggest you to navigate directly to the page because from a users point of view User will still see `Sign Up / Sign In` Buttons when they are still navigated to those pages. But if it is still a requirement. your grid should be something like above.

if you see I removed your `Tapped` events from Frame and Moved to `TextBlock` since that is where you wanted the User to Tap and Navigate to appropriate pages.

I changed `MyFrame`'s `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` . Why? Because now it will fill the whole space eliminating the need to use `Margin`

**Now to your Tap Event.**

```
private void MyFrame_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
    switch(textBlock.Text)
    {
        case "Sign in":
            MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(signin));
            break;
        case "Sign up":
            MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(signup));
            break;
    }
}
```

In XAML you can see that I used same Tapped Event on both TextBlocks. In the Event itself, I am checking which TextBlock is being called using `TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;` so that I can get correct TextBlock. Since TextBlock Text Property is different for both of them, I am Switching to Appropriate pages using this and navigating to pages related to TextBlocks.

Good Luck and Happy Coding.

Comment: Good answer ;).

Comment: Hi AVK i tried above code changes but it not worked as expected first it is giving error CS1061 'MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'TextBlock_Tapped' and no extension method 'TextBlock_Tapped' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found.  Later i removed and checked but in this case the output will be like this overlap"signin and signupt' textblock and it doesn't navigate to next page even on tapping

Comment: Thx AVK finally it helps :)